# Run function on first scroll, then never again

Tags: jquery, function, scroll

I need to run a function the first time `.scrollTop()` changes and then never again. I tried a couple things including the following, but no luck:

```
var view = $('#workspace');

view.bind("scroll resize", function() {
  doThisEveryScroll();
  if(view.scrollTop() == 3) {
    doThisOnFirstScroll();
  }
});
```

This is wrong for a number of reasons but I am not sure how to approach this any other way.

1. This will only run if the user happens to hit `.scrollTop() == 3` which isnt always the case with the scroll wheel.
2. `.scrollTop() == 3` could be true multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.one()` to setup an event handler that detaches itself once it has been called:

```
$('#workspace').on('scroll resize', function() {
  doThisEveryScroll();
}).one('scroll resize', function() {
  if (Math.abs(100 - $(this).scrollTop()) < 20) {
    doThisOnFirstScroll();
  }
});
```

You can also provide a margin of error for your target scroll position by calculating the distance from your target:

```
Math.abs(100 - $(this).scrollTop()) < 20
```

This will return `true` if the user is within `20px` of `100px`.

Comment: `.one` is exactly what I was looking for. I stuck with `.bind` instead of `.on` though. For some reason I got an error saying my object did not support `.on`. Your margin of error trick is clever but I just used `if (view.scrollTop() > 0)` since I only need it to happen on the first scroll. Thanks!